# string parsing using cmd commands

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file, cmd

I have a cmd command that gives me output similar to below

"Targetid       = 12345"

The above string consists of \r \t \n as well.
Can you please suggest a cmd command that can help me just get the number "12345" when passed with such a string

Edit: the cmd command that i use to get above string is as follow

```
"D:\mytest\mySoftware Query <customerGUID> | findstr /R /C:""Targetid"" "
```

Comment: If you provide the `.cmd` command which outputs the string `"Targetid = 12345"`, we may have a fighting chance of helping. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49371751/edit) to include the code, _formatted correctly using the `{}` button, and any other pertinent information_.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('"D:\mytest\mySoftware Query <customerGUID>" ^| findstr /R /C:"Targetid"') do echo %%a
```

Comment: This method also includes the `\t` (TAB) or space character after the equal sign. Better: `for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ...`